# gmm (Generalized Method of Moment) versus pgmm (Generalized Method of Moment for Panel Data) in R programming

Tags: r, regression, time-series, panel-data, plm

I would like to know when I should apply gmm (generalized method of moment from 'gmm' package) or pgmm (generalized method of moment from 'plm' package) in R programming for each of the following case:

1.My data is panel data that there are several different firm names (or IDs) with several time varying variables. I also have lags for the variables as well.

--> In this case, it is obvious to use pgmm

2.My data is panel data that there are several different firm names (or IDs) with several time varying variables. I also have lags for the variables as well. However, I do not have any lags at all in any of my variables.

--> I tried using pgmm but seems like it is not working because I do not have any lags in my model at all.

3.My data is time series data with only one firm with several time varying variables. I also have lags for the variables as well.

--> I tried using pgmm but seems like not working because I do not have any difference in firm names or IDs. --> So I tried gmm instead but gmm does not seem to take lags at all.

4.My data is time series data with only one firm with several time varying variables. I do not have lags at all in the variables.

--> This may be obvious to use gmm but would like to check whether I can also use pgmm.

May I get answers for the above four questions?

Any help will be appreciated!